# How to exclude a related table when use Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

```
db.UploadFileSet.Where(f => f.Article.ID == id).ToList();
```

the ef will load the Article automatically.But I don't need it!
How can I stop it?

I know I can write like this:

```
Select new XXX{Id = xxx ,Name = xxx};
```

But this is very troublesome.

Answer (score 11):

The mentioned query will not load related articles. Those articles are loaded when you first access `Article` property in your loaded file sets (this includes access by debugger). If you want to ensure that `Article` is never lazy loaded you have to turn off lazy loading on your context - you can do that in your code by setting property in context configuration:

- ObjectContext API: `db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`
- DbContext API: `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: @Ladislav, is there a way to do this for a particular related article without affecting other related siblings?