# How can I write a simple LINQ report for a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

My application uses ASP.NET Identity 2 with tables stored in SQL Server 2012 Relational tables. Here's a view of two classes that I would like to use for reporting:

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetRoles = new List<AspNetRole>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}

public partial class AspNetRole
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I created the following LINQ to give me a report:

```
    var users = await db.AspNetUsers
        .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles)
       .ToListAsync();
```

This is inside a WebAPI method and when I check the result it gives me a 
result that I don't expect. What I see is an array of user objects and 
then inside that an array of Roles. But inside the array of Roles is
another array of users!

Here's the output that I see with some fields ommitted to make it show
easily:

```
[{"id":"27cd003a-fb6a-4a2d-8df9-f502bc10a583"
  "aspNetRoles":[
     {
      "id":"53724f55-af7a-448b-9ae2-1fe295b109fd",
      "name":"Admin",
      "aspNetUsers":[
           {
             "id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4",
           "aspNetRoles":[]
           },
           {
            "id":"e87c05bc-8305-45d0-ba07-3dd24438ba8b",
            "aspNetRoles":[]
           }
      ]},
  {"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4",
```

How can I change the LINq so that it gives me an array of `AspNetUser` objects and inside a simple array of `AspNetRole` objects? I also need the query to show me the users even if they have no roles. Something like this:

```
User1
   Role1
   Role2
User2
   Role1
User3
User4
   Role2
```

Comment: You have a User which contains a list of Roles, each of which contains a list of Users, each of which contains a list of Roles... ad infinitum.

Comment: @Tom - These are not my classes. They are the Microsoft Classes that come with Identity2. It's a many to many relationship. My question is give than this is the case then how can I make LINQ not give me a user > role > user output when I just need user > role. Thanks

Comment: You could try adding a third 'index' class AspNetUserRole, derived from Dictionary<AspNetUser,AspNetRole> that provides the mapping between users and roles, then remove the coupling between the two other classes.

Comment: Seems like it might be an issue with lazy loading automatically hydrating the relationships. To turn it off see [How to exclude a related table when use Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583545/how-to-exclude-a-related-table-when-use-entity-framework).

Comment: What's the generated SQL?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong there. A User will have Roles, each Role will also have Users which you don't have to use if you don't want to. EF is not making any extra calls, it seems you're loading all Users anyways, and EF can figure out the relationship for each Role to Users easily with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have no control over the domain classes -- they belong to Microsoft. So, what you're really saying is that you don't want to expose your domain objects directly to the rest of the world (google that and you'll find all sorts of people with opinions on that subject). So, one option is to define a set of classes which are the ones you want to expose (data exchange classes). Something like:

```
public class User
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you get your domain objects back, map them into your data exchange objects for serialization and exposure to the rest of the world.