# Ignoring Relationships in Data Returned from WCF Request

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I'm having a lot of trouble finding out information on this, but essentially too much data is being sent due to relationships within the entity framework definition.  I have a few tables, but the important one is this:  Application & Owner.  There is a one (Application) to many (Owner) relationship here due to foreign key constraints in the database. (See Below)

[image]

Here's the issue:  When I attempt to return a single Owner object all of the Application data is sent out in the XML as well, but I don't want any of this to be sent out.  Conversely, I want to be able to create a operation that has the ability to not include the owner information when Application data is sent out (although this isn't nearly as big of a deal).

I would like to maintain the FK constraint and the relationship, but limit the data that the WCF service is returning, but am running into a wall here.  What do I need to modify to make this work.

Here's the code to get an Owner object:

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Apps/{id}/{ownernum}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[Description("Gets specific owner information from the database using an appid and owner number")]
Owner GetOwnerInfo(string id, string ownernum);
```

Implementation (removed validation & other superfluous code):

```
public Owner GetOwnerInfo(string id, string ownernum)
{
     ...

    Owner owner = entities.Owners.SingleOrDefault(o => o.AppId == appId && o.OwnerNumber == ownerNumber);
    if (owner != null)
    {
        logger.Info("Owner {0} from application id {1} sent via HTTP GET", ownerNumber, appId);
        return owner;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.Warn("Cannot find owner {0} from application id {1}", ownerNumber, appId);
        throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format("Cannot find Owner {0} from AppId {1}", ownerNumber, appId), HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Can the see the code inside your web service methods? Are you using WCF Data Services?

Comment: @robbell Sure.  I'll post the code that gets an Owner.  Give me a minute to format it.

Comment: @RobBell Added...let me know if you're looking for anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reality is that you shouldn't be sending EF objects over a WCF service anyways. In fact, *most* of the time, they won't serialize at all due to the circular reference (not sure how you got around that one).

Regardless, the real solution is to create a `DataContract` with *exactly* the data you want to send over the wire, then write a translation function between that and your EF object.

Then the only objects your WCF service sends are the Data Contract objects, and you control what is/isn't sent.

Comment: this sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but haven't used it previously (I'm new to entity framework).  Do you have any links/examples to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @JNYRanger Data Contracts are actually a WCF concept. I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but here is the MSDN intro article for them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for dropping some knowledge my way!

Answer (score 1):

What @BradleyDotNet says is correct, but as a quick fix you can execute the query eagerly (via `.ToList()` or similar at the end of your query) or disable lazy loading (`context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`)

This question touches on what you're doing:

[How to exclude a related table when use Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583545/how-to-exclude-a-related-table-when-use-entity-framework)

If you need to load related items in future, use `db.MyEntity.Include(...)`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: I ended up writing some DTOs with DataContracts, but I'll keep this in mind for the future.  Thanks!